# Creating an isolated network within a school network

Tags: networking

I mentor a high school robotics club. Our network hardware consists of a 24-port switch, a Linksys WRT-54G router running dd-wrt, and a computer acting as a file server. A single ethernet connection provides access to the school's main network via the router (either wireless or through the switch connected to the router). The robot control system also connects over the network to provide wireless control/programming.

In the past, all computers connected to our network received 192.168.1.x addresses from the router's DHCP server, and communication between computers, the file server, and the robot went smoothly.

This year, computers have been receiving IP address from what I assume is the school's DHCP server (ex. 22.x.x.x, 20.x.x.x etc.) making the computers unable to communicate with each other and the file server or robot. This has also caused issues with reaching the router's config page (with its static IP set to 192.168.1.1).

The club does not have access to the school's servers or networking configuration, so I'm really trying to find a solution that can be done via router configuration. I assume the solution has to do with creating a VLAN of sorts and putting all wired and wireless connections on it, then bridging it to the port associated with the school network connection, but I'm unsure where to start.

1) Is a VLAN the correct approach? If not, what approach should I research?

2) Is the DHCP server of the router being bypassed a normal behavior?

3) Is there a guide to setting up a VLAN that receives internet access from another LAN (not WAN) port?

Any advice is appreciated. I will provide any information I can. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you speak to the school's network admins and work with them to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one of a few things may be happening:

1. Your switch is connected into the school's main network.
2. A LAN port on your router is connected to the school's main network.
3. The computers not getting DHCP assignments from your router are not actually connected to your network.
4. One of the computers on your network is running a DHCP server.

Check the following:

- Verify all connections to your switch are only coming from your computers and devices.  Make sure one of the links isn't going to the school's main network.
- Verify the only things connected to your router is your switch (via the LAN port) and the school's main network (via the WAN port).
- Verify those DHCP assignments are actual IP address from their network
- For the systems that get incorrect DHCP assignments, verify they are actually connected to your network.  If they're connected wirelessly someone might have changed where it's connecting to.  If they're connected via wire someone might have just unplugged them from your network.
- Get the MAC address of the system assigning the 'invalid' IP addresses on your network and see if it matches any of your computers or devices. This will help identify if something else on your network is acting as a dhcp server, unintentionally or otherwise.

@lain is right, work with your school's network admin(s) on this issue.  If their DHCP server really is showing up on your network there's a good chance that yours is showing up on theirs as well. If this is happening they'd want it fixed just as much as you do.

Additionally, a VLAN will not provide anything more than what your dedicated switch provides.  If something is connected to a port that belongs to that VLAN that shouldn't be connected it can still break things.